# Font forge - SVG Import not working

Tags: svg, font-forge

I am creating a "dot matrix" Kannada font.  I try to import the SVG file for a character in font forge, but its not importing in the "dot matrix" style, its getting imported as a plain line. The SVG file works perfectly when opened in image viewer with dots.

I found a work-around for this by opening the SVG file in "Libre Office Draw" > right click on the image > break.  Then again the save the image as SVG.  The problem in this method is it presents a square box for all of the dots, when i import in the font-forge, which i need to remove.

Is there any solution to this problem, where i can directly import the SVG file to font-forge instead of the workaround.

Any help is appreciated.

SVG code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" baseProfile="full" version="1.1" width="1545px" height="630px" style="fill: none; width: 1545px; height: 630px;"><path d="" style="stroke-width: 15; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke: rgb(106, 106, 106); stroke-dasharray: 1, 42;fill: none;"/><path d="" style="stroke-width: 15; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke: rgb(74, 74, 74); stroke-dasharray: 1, 42;fill: none;"/><path d="M375,180 A60,60 0 0,0 315,120 A75,90 0 0,0 240,210 L240,210 L240,300 A210,240 0 0,0 450,540 M660,210 L660,210 L660,300 A210,240 0 0,1 450,540 M660,210 A75,90 0 0,0 585,120 A75,90 0 0,0 510,210 L510,210 L510,210 L510,210 L510,210 A45,105 0 0,0 555,315 M375,180 A45,60 0 0,1 330,240 M555,315 L555,315 L405,315 " style="stroke-width: 40; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke: rgb(10, 10, 10); stroke-dasharray: 1, 42;fill: none;"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the stroke-dasharray feature of SVG to create that effect, but fonts usually don't use strokes and don't understand that. They only care about contours.

Convert your paths to outlines in Inkscape for example by using 'Path → Stroke to Path' on them.

By the way, in your SVG code, the first two <path>-elements don't have any path-data (`d=""`) so they don't actually do anything.